# Is there a known bug in Xcode and Swift UI that gives an unrelated error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I try to make a Text Field Object in my view, I get a completely unrelated error on my VStack. If I click the fix button it gives me another error. I fix that one and so on. Could you please help me with this?

The exact error I get is `Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'`

```
import SwiftUI

struct CodeLoginPage: View {

    @State public var key: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {


        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 50) {

            HStack () {

            Text("Register")
                //.font(.headline)
                .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .heavy, design: .default))

                Spacer()

            }
            .padding(.horizontal)

            TextField($key)



            Spacer()

        }
        .padding(.horizontal)


        }
    }
}

struct CodeLoginPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CodeLoginPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Error messages related to SwiftUI are notoriously vague both in their wording and in the indicated position within your code. This should improve as SwiftUI matures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to `TextField`

It should be like this `TextField("key:", text: $key)`